# Basic Matrix Multiplication Function in R

Tags: r

How could you create a function that multiplies two matrices together? I know there is a function in R that does this already, but I want to write a function that can compute this without using the function already built in R.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you. Also please make sure to show your attempts and pinpoint where your script fails.

Comment: Yes, there is already a matrix multiplication function `?\`%*%\``

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `sapply`

```
  res <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(matrix1)), function(i) sapply(seq_len(nrow(matrix2)),
                function(j) sum(matrix1[i,] * matrix2[,j])))
```

Then take a transpose of the resultant

```
res_final <- t(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would like to do this as any "user-defined" implementation is bound to be slower than the built-in R function (and you can in fact write your own C++ implementation using `Rcpp`) but here is a version

```r
matmul <- function(A, B) {
    r_A <- dim(A)[1]
    c_A <- dim(A)[2]
    r_B <- dim(B)[1]
    c_B <- dim(B)[2]

    # A and B are matrices with fitting dimensions
    if (c_A != r_B) {
        stop("Matrix dimensions not consistent")
    }

    product <- matrix(nrow = r_A, ncol = c_B)

    for (i in seq_len(r_A)) {
        for (j in seq_len(c_B)) {
            product[i,j] <- sum(A[i,] * B[,j])
        }
    }

    return(product)
}

X <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
Y <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)

print(identical(matmul(X, Y), X %*% Y))

X <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
Y <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)

print(identical(matmul(X, Y), X %*% Y))

X <- matrix(1.1:12.1, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
Y <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)

print(identical(matmul(X, Y), X %*% Y))
```

Comment: The first example will return `FALSE` since `matmul` will return a type `int` while `X %*% Y` will return type `numeric`. The second example will fail due to inconsistent dimensions and the third example will return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Given matrices `A` and `B`, for the matrix product `M = A*B`, you can used the following code:

```
M <- t(apply(A,1,function(x) apply(B,2,function(y) sum(x*y))))
```

where nested `apply()` function is the approach here.

**Example**

```
A <- matrix(1:9,ncol = 3)
B <- matrix(1:12,nrow = 3)
M <- t(apply(A, 1, function(x) apply(B,2,function(y) sum(x*y))))
```

and you will get

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   30   66  102  138
[2,]   36   81  126  171
[3,]   42   96  150  204
```

To verify the result, you can compare it with `A%*%B`, and it's shown the same result with the self-written code:

```
> A%*%B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   30   66  102  138
[2,]   36   81  126  171
[3,]   42   96  150  204
```